# Can a malicious proposer cause an infinite non-deciding scenario in 'Basic HotStuff' BFT?

Tags: pbft

The paper [HotStuff: BFT Consensus in the Lens of Blockchain](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05069.pdf) describes an infinite non-deciding scenario for a theoretical “two-phase” HotStuff variant. Specifically, the authors [claim](https://youtu.be/ONobI3X70Rc?t=1337) that the addition of a "precursor" voting round ensures that (n-f) participants know of any 'hidden/missing Lock' and a correct leader would be able to propose a value that all honest participants would accept without waiting the maximum network delay (such as Tendermint / Casper FFG).

During this precursor round, if a quorum is achieved and a certificate is created, Replicas will store the highest Precursor (PrepareQC) they know of in a local variable known as **HighQC**.

The paper details a '**SafeNodePredicate**' Replicas use to determine whether or not to accept a Proposal from a Leader.

[image: SafeNodePredicate]

However, within the **SafeNodePredicate** the **HighQC** (highest Precursor) of any Replica is never checked against the proposal. Could a malicious Proposer simply choose to ignore a **HighQC** removing the safety properties of the Precursor round and forcing a 'Hidden Lock'?